# Get Polish Zloty in Malaysia

Tags: exchange

Good morning !!

I want to exchange Malaysian Ringgit for Polish Zloty. But all the standard money exchangers are not providing PLN. Is there any other provider?

Comment: What do you need PLN for? If you are going to travel to Poland, would exchanging it in Poland be acceptable for you?

Comment: Maybe exchange Ringgit for EUR or US-Dollar and get Zloty in Poland if you are traveling.

Comment: Are you going to be traveling to Poland soon, or do you need Zloty for some other purpose?

Answer (score 3):

If you want this for purpose of using this cash in Poland, you're better off buying `EUR` or `USD`, and exchanging these into `PLN` when you arrive in Poland. Most preferable is to not use exchange booths at the airport if possible, as they usually provide worse rate.

This is universal rule when travelling, you want to carry hard widely-circulated cash with you (which is almost always `USD`, maybe `EUR` if you are travelling from/to Europe, maybe it's Yen or Yuan in Asia, I can't tell), because these offer very good rates when exchanging from/to them, meaning you don't lose that much money on the transaction. Exchanging from one non-widely-circulated cash to another one usually results in much worse rate. There are exceptions for countries which have a huge flow of money between them, but it's hard to tell without knowing.

You can also usually pay with your card, the rate is usually pretty good. It may be worse when withdrawing cash, so it is advised to carry some hard cash for exchange.